# Use of "need attended"

Tags: verbs

A coworker insisted that this sentence was incorrect but I argued that it is correct. Here is the sentence in question:

> There are potholes that need attended to right away on southbound I-75
>   near Dearborn Street.

Comment: Should be "need to be attended to", "need attending to", "need tending to", "need attention", and several others.

Comment: At first this sounded okay to me, but then again, I'm an uneducated Pennsylvanian...!

Comment: I grew up in Oakdale, Pa. I left 40  years ago and it sounds perfectly fine to me. Never knew it was regional. The car needs gassed, the dog wants fed, and the weeds need sprayed.

Comment: Ah shucks. Somebody deleted their comment about how this makes sense to uneducated Pennsylvanians, so now my comment makes me look even more uneducated!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your original tone, then you could use:

"There are potholes that need **tending to** right away on southbound I-75 near Dearborn Street.

OR you can be a bit more direct with it:

"There are potholes that need **immediate attention** on southbound I-75 near Dearborn Street."

Comment: Not 'tending to' unless you're from my neck of the woods :).

Comment: @John
From:  http://www.dictionary.com/browse/tending

tend

verb (used with object)
1. to attend to by work or services, care, etc.:
to tend a fire.

Comment: To my ear "tending" (without the following "to") only applies to something like a fire which requires regular and repeated attention.  One would hope that potholes are fixed properly and would not need such regular attention (though I suppose in some cities that may not be the case).

Comment: @John What is your "neck of the woods"? "need tending to" sounds perfectly fine to me (as a Brit), even if not very common.

Comment: @TrevorD, Texas. To me, it comes across sounding hillbilly. It has a colloquial feel to me. 'Git tendin to yur crops', 'Best tend yur bizness now'. But good to know.  Thanks.

Comment: This answer was automatically flagged as low-quality because of its length and content.
A suggestion is not an answer.
A good answer is comprehensive and contains evidence showing why it is correct.
Links to external resources are encouraged.
Answers which consist of virtually nothing but an unsupported statement or a citation are not useful and may be subject to deletion – even correct answers.
For an introduction to the site, take the [Tour]. For help writing a good answer, see [answer].

Answer (score -3):

Your coworker is correct.

The sentence in question should be:

> There are potholes that **need to be attended** right away on southbound I-75 near Dearborn Street.

Or:

> There are potholes that **need attending** right away on southbound I-75 near Dearborn Street.

Source: http://microsyntax.sites.yale.edu/needs-washed

Comment: Except in those dialects where "needs attended" are grammatical. Central Pennsylvanian, according to the comment above, and also parts of Northern England and Scotland.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but maybe it's because it should be 'need to be attended _to_'.

Comment: Both of them need, at minimum, a "to" ahead of "right away".

Comment: If you *attend to* a pothole, you mean you pay attention to it. If you *attend* a pothole, you mean it's an event, like a rally or concert which you *attend*.